# Need to click the page before i am able to click any links

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using JQuery and MVC3 razor on a project and I have a rather strange issue with mouse clicks.
What happens is that when the page loads, I am forced to click somewhere in the page before the mouse/browser/webpage recognizes that I am clicking on a link. This happens on every page, regardless of what link, button, input, etc. that I click.

I could post some code, but I am not sure which code to post since this problem permeates the entire site and there is way more code than I could possibly get into one post. I believe it has something to do with jquery/javascript but I am unsure.

I am at a loss as to where to look for the problem, has anyone ran into this problem before? If so, how did you correct the issue?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you re-create in a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it must be a presentational problem, maybe related to some CSS issue, could you [JSFiddle it](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Or maybe test your own page without any CSS ? (just comment out the CSS link tag)

Comment: good suggestion, I think commenting out chucks of stuff is the way to go to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: This sometimes happens when z-indexes in the CSS create a ordering problem.

Comment: I removed the CSS files and nothing changed, so I went to JSFiddle and went one by one through the scripts that I have in the project and was able to find the solution. Apparently the Masked input plugin I am using to mask out the phone number input boxes was stealing the focus from the window on page load which meant that I had to click inside the window to regain focus. I fixed this by adding the line window.focus() after setting the mask on the input boxes.  Thanks for the good suggestions, I will mark as the answer since it led me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to search your entire solution for all `.click(` and `bind('click'` pretty much all jquery click events and see if all the click events you've defined in your project are legit.  Also I would suggest starting to peel of layers of script and CSS to see if you can replicate the problem; comment out all CSS and see if you notice the issue then start commenting out all core JS.  I think there is something subtle that you are doing in your CSS or Java Script that's causing this issue and you need to work back wards to find out what it is.